# PHP header read file and redirect

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to redirect my user after they download my files. I manage to make them download the file but I cant redirect them to the url. Pleas help

```
<?php
//Search for file using GET
if(isset ($_GET['file']) && ($_GET['url'])){

    $file = $_GET['file'];
    $link = $_GET['url'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;

    } else {

        echo "Why are you here?";
    }

//file downloaded now go to link
header('Location: $link');

}

?>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `"` here `header('Location: $link');`.

Comment: Nothing after the exit () will run

Comment: @Dagon removed the exit still doesnt redirect

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible what you do and want.

- your redirect will be executed if the GET parameters *file* and *url* exist and the physic file *not exists*.
- if GET parameters *file* and *url* exist and the physic file *exists*, you exit after the download (script stops with further execution).

Why not a redirect from html code to your download script. Many downloads site work with.

As pseudo, redirect.html:

```
html
   head
      redirect to your forced download file FOO after X seconds with e.g. meta tag
   /head
   body
      Download of file FOO starts in X seconds
   /body
/html
```

In the case above you don't need the php redirect, only the force download. Set the redirect script *not in the same file* as your download script!

Answer (score -1):

You got the wrong quotes:

```
header("Location: $link"); // note the "
```

Or do concatenation:

```
header('Location: '.$link);
```

By the way, the way you're doing what you want to do is basically a good way to let anyone with HTTP 80 access to this script to download any file on your server. What if `$file = '/etc/passwd';`?

Comment: @teststack: Can you `var_dump($link);` before you check if file exists?

Answer (score -1):

remove exit; from true part and try to put this instead

```
header('Location: $link');
```